# How to highlight formatted strings with ng-select?

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, angular-ngselect

I am using ng-select and ng-select/ng-option-highlight for a dropdown input field.

In the dropdown I have IBANs. I have formatted the IBANs with a pipe, so that they have a visually appealing form (**** **** **** ****).

I would like to highlight the IBANs as the user types the strings into the search field. But, because of the formatting, highlighting stops at the whitespaces:

'123455' --> "**1234** 5566 4555 0550"

If I enter a whitespace into the search field, the highlighting disappears.

I have tried removing all whitespaces with a pipe, but it doesn't help:

```
<ng-select [items]="accounts" 
           bindLabel="name" 
           bindValue="id" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">

    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
        <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search | nospace">{{item.iban | iban}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from "@angular/core";

@Pipe({ name: 'nospace' })
export class NoSpacePipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    if (!value) {
      return '';
    }

    return value.replace(/\s/g, "");
  }
}
```

I have also tried adding the IBAN formatting pipe. It almost works as expected, but not quite.

If the IBAN is '1234 4556 4545 0000' and I enter '123455' it displays "**1234** **55**6 4**55**5 0**55**0".

```
<ng-select [items]="accounts" 
           bindLabel="name" 
           bindValue="id" 
           [(ngModel)]="selectedAccount">

    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item" let-search="searchTerm">
        <span [ngOptionHighlight]="search | iban">{{item.iban | iban}}</span>
    </ng-template>
</ng-select>
```

What I would like:
'123455' --> "**1234** **55**6 4555 0550".

How can I highlight these IBANS correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do that, search term is escaped, splitted by space and transformed into regex, see https://github.com/ng-select/ng-select/blob/be0fa91293c5cbec71da0f151639342d1b6f1c76/src/ng-option-highlight/lib/ng-option-highlight.directive.ts#L51

I think the most reasonable way to do that is to clone `NgOptionHighlightDirective` and alter highlighting logic.